# Software Recommendation for Card Layout

Tags: print-design, page-layout, batch-processing

I am looking to design many unique study cards, with text and some images on the front and back, to be printed on a professional digital press. Right now, I have the material in a table, with one row per card to be printed.

My question is: what tool can I use to convert a long list of source material into mostly-laid-out cards? I may have to do some manual tweaking, but is there some tool to bulk-import these card lists into a layout document?

Note that this is a different problem than a mail merge or greeting-card run, because each of the cards I am making is unique, in a set of about 1000. I don't want the same card 1000 times; rather, I want to bulk-import many unique cards and then adjust by hand.

Comment: Sorry; do you mean that the cards will be identical - _except_ for text? Or will some be different visually? You _could_ do it in excel/word, but for the professional approach, I would suggest InDesign.

Comment: They will all be the same size and shape, but the contents of each will be different. I am looking for the way people recommend going from a table of words, with a column for the front and one for the back, to a set of pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been messing around with [Flat](http://xxyxyz.org/flat/) and [Even](http://xxyxyz.org/even/) from [http://xxyxyz.org/](http://xxyxyz.org). Flat is a graphics toolkit written in Python. Even is a presentation gui and python editor. It's very handy for mocking up pdf documents programatically.

If you are an inDesign user, you can use [Adobe's scripting features](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/indesign/documentation.html) or [basil.js](http://basiljs.ch/), a plugin that uses a more processing-like syntax for manipulating inDesign documents.

Comment: Looks like I will be using a custom program along these lines to convert the raw data into layouts. Thanks!